# bulkification issue for insert operation of attachment

Tags: attachment, dml, bulkification

I am getting bulkification issue on "insert at".Not able to understand why there is bulkification issue.Below is my code.

```
public static Attachment addAttach(Attachment at) {
        try {
            if(at != null) {
                insert at;
            }
            return at;
        }
        catch(DMLException exceptionMessage) {
            system.debug(exceptionMessage.getmessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This piece of code is inside a DAO class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are calling `addAttach()` method in a loop which in turn triggering `DML (insert)` statement.

Best way to handle this, change the parameter `Attachment at` to `List<Attachment>` and from the calling method pass the `attachments` as list and perform the DML in `addAttach()` on that list.